# If two functions are equal in $L^2$, are they equal in other spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f\in L^{2}$ and $g\in W^{k,2}$ and assume that

$(f,v)_{L^2}=(g,v)_{L^2}\quad \forall v\in L^2$.

Does this imply that $f=g$ and therefore $f$ is in $W^{k,2}$

Comment: Yes $f=g$ a.s. Take $v=f-g$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The equality is an equality as L^2 functions. Does it follow easily that the equality is also in other spaces? For example, if the equality is meant as a pointwise equality, the result is false, as equality only can be satisfied a.e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of Bananach:

Using $v=f-g$ one can see that they are equal in $L^2$.

Because $W^{k,2}$ is a subspace of $L^2$, it follows that
$f\in W^{k,2}$ and $f=g$ in W^{k,2}$.

As you said, we also know that $f = g$ almost everywhere.

There are spaces where the above would not be true.
For instance, if we replace $W^{k,2}$ with $C[0,1]$ in the question,
then $f$ does not need to be continuous, but $f$ is equal a.e.\ to the continuous function $g$.

Comment: Is there a proof that they are equal in $W^{k,2}$? It can't just be because $W^{k,2}$ is a subspace because then they would be equal in C[0,1].